# PHP returns "unexpected semicolon" error

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

So I have a php file called Time.php:

```
 <?php echo (( $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Hour + ":" + $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s
 A").Minute + ":" + $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Second ) ?>
```

This was originally in ASP, but I used a translator tool to get it into PHP, so it might be syntactically incorrect. Whenever I launch the page in my localhost, it gives me an error, saying there's an unexpected semicolon on line 2. In my file, as opposed to the above, line 2 is `":" + $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Second ) ?>`. As you can already see there are no semicolons in the entire file, let alone in the second line. Why is it giving me this error (I'm using WAMPserver, it's turned on, working, etc)?

Comment: I had that error when I tried it for the first time, and there was a semicolon at the end, which I removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in PHP are:

```
$DateTime->date("n/j/Y g:i:s A")->Hour
```

**not**

```
$DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Hour
```

String concatenation is done like:

```
echo "Hello" . "World";
```

**not**

```
echo "Hello" + "World";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many open brackets.

```
<?php echo ( $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Hour + ":" + $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Minute + ":" + $DateTime.date("n/j/Y g:i:s A").Second ) ?>
```

Comment: That now gives me all sorts of errors about undefined variables. Is there any other way of giving the date and time in PHP?

Comment: That's a separate issue which @iambriansreed is attempting to solve for you.

Comment: @Bluefire I answered your question. You need to do some research and if you get stuck then ask your date question separately.

Comment: Nvm, I just used `<?php echo (date("h:i:s"))?>`. Thanks for the help though.